Mean squared error of MLE of $\theta$ where $f(x) = 3x^2 \theta e^{-\theta x^3} 1_{(0,\infty)}(x)$
Given $f(x) = 3x^2 \theta e^{-\theta x^3} 1_{(0,\infty)}(x)$ I want to find the MSE of the MLE estimator for $\theta$. I've found that $\hat{\theta} = \frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^3} = \frac{1}{\bar{X^3}}$.
I know that $MSE(\hat{\theta}) = Var(\hat{\theta}) + Bias(\hat{\theta})^2$ but I am having trouble finding $E(\hat{\theta})$ and $E(\hat{\theta}^2)$ here. How should I proceed?

The density you have specified,
$$f_X(x) = 3\theta e^{-\theta x^3} \mathbb 1 (x > 0), \tag{1}$$
is not a proper density because it does not integrate to $1$:
$$\int_{x=0}^\infty 3\theta e^{-\theta x^3} \, dx = \Gamma(\tfrac{1}{3}) \theta^{2/3}. \tag{2}$$  The constant factor $\Gamma(\tfrac{1}{3})$ is not problematic because we can always rescale the density by such a constant.  However, the $\theta^{2/3}$ factor is a problem, because it is a function of the parameter, hence the kernel of this density is misspecified.
Possible valid densities might include
$$f_X(x) = \frac{\theta e^{-(\theta x)^3}}{\Gamma(\tfrac{4}{3})} \mathbb 1 (x > 0), \tag{3}$$
or
$$f_X(x) = 3\theta^3 x^2 e^{-(\theta x)^3} \mathbb 1(x > 0), \tag{4}$$
the latter of which is a Weibull distribution with shape $3$ and rate $\theta$.  Please clarify the correct density for $X$.

With the density $$f_X(x) = 3\theta x^2 e^{-\theta x^3} \mathbb 1(x > 0), \tag{5},$$
we have the likelihood for a sample $(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$
$$\mathcal L(\theta \mid x_1, \ldots, x_n) \propto \theta^n e^{-\theta \sum x_i^3} \mathbb 1 (x_{(1)} > 0). \tag{6}$$  Hence the log-likelihood is
$$\ell(\theta \mid x_1, \ldots, x_n) \propto n \log \theta - \theta \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^3 \tag{7}$$
and its critical points satisfy
$$0 = \frac{\partial \ell}{\partial \theta} = \frac{n}{\theta} - \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^3. \tag{8}$$
Hence our MLE is
$$\hat \theta = \frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^3}, \tag{9}$$
This suggests computing the PDF of the transformed variable $Y = X^3$:
$$f_Y(y) = f_X(y^{1/3}) \left|\frac{d}{dy} y^{1/3}\right| = \frac{1}{3y^{2/3}} 3\theta (y^{1/3})^2 e^{-\theta y} \mathbb 1 (y > 0) = \theta e^{-\theta y} \mathbb 1 (y > 0); \tag{10}$$ that is to say, $Y = X^3$ is exponential with rate $\theta$.  Consequently, $$S = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^3 \sim \operatorname{Gamma}(n, \theta), \tag{11}$$
is the sum of $n$ iid exponential random variables, hence is gamma distributed with shape $n$ and rate $\theta$.  Its reciprocal $1/S = \hat \theta/n$ is therefore inverse gamma distributed:
$$f_{\hat \theta/n}(t) = f_S(1/t) \left|\frac{d}{dt} [1/t]\right| = \frac{\theta^n (1/t)^{n-1} e^{-\theta/t}}{\Gamma(n)} \cdot \frac{1}{t^2} \mathbb 1(t > 0) = \frac{\theta^n e^{-\theta/t}}{t^{n+1} \Gamma(n)} \mathbb 1 (t > 0). \tag{12}$$
I leave it as an exercise to show using $(12)$
$$\operatorname{E}[\hat \theta/n] = \frac{\theta}{n-1}, \quad n > 1, \tag{13}$$
$$\operatorname{E}[(\hat \theta/n)^2] = \frac{\theta^2}{(n-1)(n-2)}, \quad n > 2, \tag{14}$$
from which you should be able to compute the mean square error of $\hat \theta$.

You are absolutely right! Typo is now corrected, my apologies.

@SaimFaigol Please see updated answer.
